# Calling a function within one class that calls a function within a separate class python

Tags: python, oop, methods

I am having trouble trying to call a function with one class that calls a separate function that exists within another class.

```
class PrintNum():

    def get_square(self):
        Numbers.square_Num(self)

    def Print_Num(self):
        Numbers.square_Num(self)

class Numbers():
    def __init__(self, num1,num2):
        self.num1=num1
        self.num2=num2

    def show_num(self):
        return self.num1,self.mum2,

    def square_Num(self):
        self.num1,self.mum2, = self.num1**2,self.num2**2


p2= PrintNum(3,6)
p2.get_square()

print(p2.Print_Num)
```

Comment: You aren’t instantiating a Numbers object anywhere. What result are you expecting from a square function with no number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Get Such Behaviour from your classes, You need to use either inheritance or Embed the class. I used embedding to solve the problem above although I feel inheritance might be better suited here.

```
class PrintNum():

    def __init__(self,a1,a2):
        self.numbers = Numbers(a1,a2)
    def get_square(self):
        self.numbers.square_Num(self)
    def Print_Num(self):
        print(self.numbers)
class Numbers():

    def __init__(self, num1,num2):
        self.num1=num1
        self.num2=num2
    def __repr__(self):
        print(self.num1)
        return self.num2
    def square_Num(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.num1,self.num2 = self.num1**2,self.num2**2
```

```
p2= PrintNum(3,6)

p2.get_square()

p2.Print_Num()
```

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
class PrintNum:

    def get_square(self):
        Numbers().square_Num()

    def Print_Num(self):
        Numbers().square_Num()
```

The methods of the `Numbers` class are *instance* methods - they need to be called on an *instance* of the class, not the class itself.  We make an instance by calling the class:

```
numbers_instance = Numbers()
```

So in `PrintNum`'s methods we create an instance of `Numbers` before calling the methods.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you are not using classes correctly. The parameter `self` references the object instance you created of the given class. You should not try to access it outside of the instance methods of a class. Trying to pass the `self` parameter to a different class will not work because they would represent two different object instances. In this case, you never instantiate a `Numbers` object at all, so it has no instance. To do this properly, instantiate a Numbers instance inside of `PrintNum` and then call its instance methods like so:

```
class PrintNum():
    def __init__(self):
        self.numbers = Numbers()

    def get_square(self):
        return self.numbers.square_number()

    def print_number(self):
        return self.numbers.show_num()

class Numbers():
    def __init__(self):
        self.num1=2
        self.num2=3

    def show_num(self):
        return self.num1,self.mum2

    def square_number(self):
        self.num1,self.mum2 = self.num1**2,self.num2**2


p2= PrintNum()
p2.get_square()

print(p2.print_number())
```

Comment: Also, watch for trailing commas in parameters like this. It can be a beast to hunt down the weird behavior this might introduce. For example, `self.num1,self.mum2,`. Notice the trailing comma. Depending on how things are implemented, this could result in a 3 item tuple instead of the 2 item tuple you seem to want.